# How can I narrow down a value in a function that takes in a key and a value

Tags: typescript, type-inference, type-narrowing

I'm trying to create a function which can take a key of a type and a value corresponding to that key. Then I want to do something when I'm looking at a specific key.
My specific use case for this is a Table component I've built in React that iterates through an Objects entries and passes the key and value into a separate function and I want to provide the ability to override this safely.

I've simplified a bit and implemented this. I have the type User and a function that prints the name contained within the user details. However `value.name` is not being narrowed and cannot be accessed.

```
type User = {
    details: {
        name: string;
    };
    account: {
        status: boolean;
    }
}

const printName =  <K extends keyof User>(key: K, value: User[K]) => {
    if (key === 'details') {
        console.log(value.name); // Doesn't work
    }
}

const user: User = {
    details: {
        name: 'Bob'
    },
    account: {
        status: true
    }
}

printName('details', user.details);
```

The code above produces this type error:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ name: string; } | { status: boolean; }'.
Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ status: boolean; }'.(2339)
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjqATCYAQwEsAbOALg21zoDsiBbCauYRE+gcwG5acAX350iAYzEB7AK71g1LHTrsiwaVSgAjSZLIQi9EbkGYTmKfXZQwnOQDlm0NFAA8AaSgQAHsAj08cFAA1hAgkgBmsAiIAHwAFCEg1G4ANFAAbkRk0qxRSADabgC6AJSoMTR0JJEJoagoaADkBMTkcI1liko4FnC6EAB0ZJLccZnZg4wsJbxQAPRzUAAikhBw9I3AUADukohBAlAmZr1b6kjU8EiolbgtpBQKhwyO1I0AQpKajYeCKYfiKSyeS3boqNQaDg5X6mTCYGxcYAOFhxZqEB7tNLnRADe5tGZAA)

Comment: That only works from _outside_ the function (e.g. `printName('details', user.account)` would fail). Checking `key` won't have any impact on the type of `value`, I think you'd need e.g. `(value as User['details']).name`.

Comment: Currently in TS, generics and narrowing don't play nicely together.  If your function is generic, your implementation won't be able to do narrowing the way you want.  And if you want narrowing, then your function needs to take unions, not generics.  I can refactor your function to be non-generic [like this](https://tsplay.dev/NdyQ6m) and you get the narrowing you're looking for.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?